# Pac file not working as proxy for ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, ipad-2, ipad-3

I am attempting to setup a pac file as proxy for an ipad running ios version 8.4.  I setup the ipad to use the proxy by pointing the auto configuration url under wifi settings to point the pac file:

https://myproxyserver:2020/proxy.pac

This is the contents of proxy.pac:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) 
{
    return "PROXY http://internalproxy:8080";
}
```

Then I try to connect to the internet using safari and it does not work.  I get an error:

"Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding."

I know the proxy works on the ipad since if I set the wifi settings to manual and point to http://internalproxy:8080 directly, I can then get to the internet with no errors.

Also, I know the iPad can get to the proxy pac file, since if I remove all proxy settings and point directly to:

https://myproxyserver:2020/proxy.pac

I can get to the file.

What am I missing?  Thanks.

References:
http://www.amsys.co.uk/2012/05/how-to-use-a-pac-file-in-ios/